# Error when compiling Qt project. The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2. Make file issue

Tags: python, c++, qt, makefile, qmake

I am trying to run a QT project on my Ubuntu machine and have been stuck on this error for days now.
Can someone please help me?

I do not exactly follow what the problem might be here. I tried many combinations of Libs in the .pro file but nothing works and I am not sure what's wrong.
Here the error says that cannot open the /bin/sh file. I tried using "sudo make" as well but it gave the same error.

```
g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/xxx/miniconda3/lib -o imgCodecs main.o imgcodecs.o randommask.o supplementary_functions.o masks.o reggridmaskdialog.o eedinpaintingdialog.o inpainting.o derivatives.o fed.o xorresdialog.o diffresdialog.o foeedinpaintingdialog.o eedsmoothingdialog.o smoothing.o timeaxiscombinedialog.o chain_coding.o slicewiseeeddialog.o eed_4_4d_dialog.o directneighbordilationdialog.o primizedialog.o r_ilh_0_dialog.o nifti1_io.o znzlib.o CannyEdgeDetector.o moc_imgcodecs.o moc_randommask.o moc_reggridmaskdialog.o moc_eedinpaintingdialog.o moc_xorresdialog.o moc_diffresdialog.o moc_foeedinpaintingdialog.o moc_eedsmoothingdialog.o moc_timeaxiscombinedialog.o moc_chain_coding.o moc_slicewiseeeddialog.o moc_eed_4_4d_dialog.o moc_directneighbordilationdialog.o moc_primizedialog.o moc_r_ilh_0_dialog.o   -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lpython<version> -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -L/home/xxx/miniconda3/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/bin/sh: 1: cannot open version: No such file
make: *** [Makefile:378: imgCodecs] Error 2
15:36:10: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project imgCodecs (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.9 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

The rest of the error file can be found here https://pastebin.com/XzgyBHEz

here is the make file line 378 which is the indicative at the error log

```
373 
374 first: all
375 ####### Build rules
376 
377 $(TARGET): ui_imgcodecs.h ui_randommask.h ui_reggridmaskdialog.h ui_eedinpaintingdialog.h ui_xorresdialog.h ui_diffresdialog.h ui_foeedinpaintingdialog.h ui_eedsmoothingdialog.h ui_timeaxiscombinedi     alog.h ui_chain_coding.h ui_slicewiseeeddialog.h ui_eed_4_4d_dialog.h ui_directneighbordilationdialog.h ui_primizedialog.h ui_r_ilh_0_dialog.h $(OBJECTS)
378         $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJCOMP) $(LIBS)
379
```

Comment: What's `-lpython<version>` in your command? The error message says "cannot open `version`: No such file", so it's trying to find a file called `version`, but there's no such file

Comment: Apparently you're supposed to edit the makefile or some configuration file and replace the string `<version>` with the version of Python you want to link with.

Comment: The .pro file had the link to python<version> and on changing it worked. thanks